# How I can convert an docx into pdf using phpWord template engine?

Tags: php, pdf, docx, laravel-5.7, phpword

I made a quick controller in order to test how I can convert a docx template into pdf after replacing placeholder values. The .docx is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14-Nh0L-R7ulHgpmTN5s-T0PilwWSsE7L/view?usp=sharing

And I use the following laravel code to convet it from docx template into pdf

```
namespace App\Controllers\Services;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

class Contract extends BaseController
{
    public function getContract()
    {
        $file = storage_path()."/contracts/contract.docx";
        $tmpFile = storage_path()."/contracts/output.pdf";

        $template = new TemplateProcessor($file);
        $template->setValue('COMP_NAME',"LOREM IPSUM INC");
        $template->setValue('ADDRESS',"Nowhere Str Tsastikistan");
        $template->saveAs($tmpFile);

        return Response::make("OK");
    }
}
```

But the code fails to generate a readable pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wYsVrjwQNMN8r3sWZlOm6x7cNeja3ET0/view?usp=sharing

Ι also tried to generate an html so I can convert it into pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wYsVrjwQNMN8r3sWZlOm6x7cNeja3ET0/view?usp=sharing

But still the output seebs pretty much garbage.

Therefore do you have any idea how I can convert a docx template in PDF, if yes how I can use in-memory file instead of the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Directly you cannot. You need to save it as docx first and thean read it again and save it as PDF:

```
namespace App\Controllers\Services;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

class Contract extends BaseController
{
    public function getContract()
    {
        $file = storage_path()."/contracts/contract.docx";
        $tmpFile = storage_path()."/contracts/output.pdf";
        $outfile = storage_path()."/contracts/output.docx";

        $template = new TemplateProcessor($file);
        $template->setValue('COMP_NAME',"LOREM IPSUM INC");
        $template->setValue('ADDRESS',"Nowhere Str Tsastikistan");
        $template->saveAs($outfile);

        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($outfile);
        $phpWord->save($tmpFile,'PDF');        

        return Response::make("OK");
    }
}
```

A solution I have not tested though is to use `php://temp` or `php://memory` in order to avoid filesystem IO.

Comment: This completely removes all the styling on my end, could that be possible?